# Sphinx restart search demon issue for reindexing Delta Indexes

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, full-text-search, sphinx

I’m working on my application search engine. This search engine is using sphinx for fulltext searching.

I created a cron job which is responsible for updating indexes. Currently it is set to execute once in a day.

Here what im doing in this cron.

```
   indexer --all --rotate > sphinx.log
```

Sometimes the whole search module goes down and it shows this error on client application.

```
Notice (1024): Search query failed: connection to 127.0.0.1:9312 failed (errno=111, msg=Connection refused) [APP/models/behaviors/sphinx.php, line 134]
```

And on sphinx.log I found this error

```
FATAL: failed to lock /usr/local/sphinxsearch/delta_users/delta_users.spl: Resource temporarily unavailable, will not index. Try --rotate option.
```

It seems like 9312 is refused to connect, probably this is because the resource files are used by some other process. This is random behavior yet.

The environment is deployed on Linux (ubuntu) and application is created on cakephp.
I’m trying to identify what cause it stops from restarting sphinx service again. I don’t know either this is sphinx configuration issue or some I/O or mysql problem. I think delta indexes causing some problem only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually when it rotates all indexes i.e main and delta indexes altogether it locks the resource file of delta indexes. I moved the rotation of delta indexes with other cron job which is responsible for merging delta indexing.

```
indexer   delta_users delta_users_type
indexer --merge users  delta_users 
indexer --merge users_type delta_users_type
```

And rotate only main indexes separately on different cron

```
indexer --rotate -- users  users_type
```

instead of

```
indexer --rotate -- all
```

Hence the separate rotation of Delta and Main index is the resolution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check which users run searchd and indexer processes. Also see what permissions you have on the index files. You are having a permission issue.

Comment: the user of searchd and indexer processes are same and I've given all read write permission to index files. I told you it is random behaviour